# Paypal Payment Buttons - Can You Dynamically Set the Price

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

I am certainly interested in using PayPal's Standard payment buttons; however, I would like to be able to set the amount myself in code, instead of being forced to create a button with a fixed amount through Paypal. For example, I thought the following code would work:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This does not work either:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="U7K937HLYPW6L">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Instead of directing the user to a page where they could make a payment of 5.00, the page instead allows users to input their own amount. In my real application, I would use PHP to calculate the total (at a cart style page) and associate that value with the 'amount' key, but I cannot even get it to work even with static values. What is the solution?

Thanks much!

Comment: Paypal hosted/encrypted buttons are securely implemented to prevent manipulation of the transaction outside of _what you defined_. You can certainly implement Paypal dynamically without using "pre-defined buttons", but it will be up to you to secure your implementation from tampering of details.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to utilise their [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) to produce dynamic pricing to break away from the "cart" type system provided by paypal. Essentially you would look to replace the paypal "cart" page with your own by coding using the API.